# Laravel Subdomain Based Authentication Not working in Production

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, subdomain, laravel-5.7

I have to build a multi-tenant app using laravel and added a subdomain middleware to change database on request. I have changed the `SESSION_DOMAIN='.example.com'` and also changed the session driver to the database. My application exactly works in localhost `tenant.localhost:8000/login` by redirecting to dashboard. But in live server `http:\\tenant.example.com/login` when i login it gives me the follow error. 
[image]

My **web.php**
[image]

Comment: Most likely not the problem, but you shouldn't use `env()` outside config files. Once you cache your config, the environment file will not be loaded anymore, leading to weird observations.

Comment: Why are there multiple logout routes (both `get`)?

Comment: @Namoshek sorry that's a redundant logout route.. Ignore it. Now what should i do to solve this issue.

Comment: Remove the leading dot in the production URL.

Comment: @Namoshek leading dot is removed in production URL. Still the problem exists. Its now `$domain = env('APP_ENV') == 'local' ? 'localhost' : 'runnerhit.com';`

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely is that you use `localhost` locally but `.runnerhit.com` in production. The difference is the leading dot `.` which is redundant to the one in your route group definition.

Comment: I've removed the leading `.` but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this situation. Please ensure you use route name not Url in code 
Let suppose your route is :

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home.index');
```

use route('home.index') instead of url('/')

Answer (score 0):

My approach to multiple database multi-tenancy looks something like this...

In the `.env` file I added the databases.

```
# Database: Client 1
CLIENT_ONE_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
CLIENT_ONE_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
CLIENT_ONE_DB_PORT=3306
CLIENT_ONE_DB_DATABASE=client_one_db
CLIENT_ONE_DB_USERNAME=root
CLIENT_ONE_DB_PASSWORD=

# Database: Client 2
CLIENT_TWO_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
CLIENT_TWO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
CLIENT_TWO_DB_PORT=3306
CLIENT_TWO_DB_DATABASE=client_two_db
CLIENT_TWO_DB_USERNAME=root
CLIENT_TWO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

In the `config/database.php` file I add the databases.

```
'client_one' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('CLIENT_ONE_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],

'client_two' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('CLIENT_TWO_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

I create a config file for setting the connection at `/config/connection.php` that looks like this...

```
<?php

$domain = request()->getHttpHost();
$domain_parts = explode('.', $domain);
$subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

if ($subdomain == 'clientone') {
    config()->set('database.default', 'client_one');
}

if ($subdomain == 'clienttwo') {
    config()->set('database.default', 'client_two');
}

return ['subdomain' => $subdomain];
```

That's about it.  I don't have to mess with the routes or middleware, both of which come with their deeper challenges.  This approach keeps everything separate and simple.

Also, by returning `subdomain` in a config, you'll have access to that constant elsewhere in your app.  So for example, in a blade file, if you want the navbar logo area of your app to display the client name you can use...

```
{{ config('connection.subdomain') }}
```

This is what I chose to do after a ton of research.  Hopefully this approach will help others do the same thing I was attempting to do.